# TextFieldParser adding zeros to number in CSV

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I'm using TextFieldParser to read a CSV file. This particular column in the CSV contains numbers: 3.14, 2.65, etc. I'm reading them as such:

```
        var path = @"C:\myfiles\file.csv";
        using (TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(path))
        {
            csvParser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });                

            csvParser.ReadLine();

            var numbers = new string[5];
            numbers[0] = csvParser.ReadFields()[23];
            numbers[1] = csvParser.ReadFields()[23];
            numbers[2] = csvParser.ReadFields()[23];
            numbers[3] = csvParser.ReadFields()[23];
            numbers[4] = csvParser.ReadFields()[23];

            return numbers;
        }
```

This works, but the strings I'm getting back have two zeros appended; ie. 3.14 is returned as "3.1400". Is there a reason this is happening? A configuration option for the TextFieldParser, perhaps?

Comment: The `TextFieldParser` is swell but it only returns strings.  Other tools like `CSVHelper`, for example will return property typed data and collections

Comment: Not worried about that, I have some string manipulation to do on the results anyway.

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure the text file itself doesn't have the extra zeroes? That makes the most sense, especially given that we are dealing with straight `string`s here.

Comment: It would be good to see the file you are reading. `ReadFields` reads a text file and returns strings. At no point in your code is "3.14" considered to be a number, so there is no reason for _any_ characters to be appended, zeroes or otherwise. The fact that you are seeing zeroes suggests that they are either there in the file itself (open your CSV in a tex file viewer (not Excel) to check), or you are not viewing them as strings.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to parse the returned strings to floats like this:

`parseFloat(csvParser.ReadFields()[23]);`

In this case you should change your array-type from string to number. Or generate a string again with `toString()`-Method after parsing it to float.

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that the code works without the additional trailing "00".  If you put a breakpoint at each of the numbers[x] you will find that it does not contain additional characters.  My feeling is that your bug is elsewhere...

At least when I replicated your code in LINQPad, it did not produce the error that you describe...

Answer (score 0):

If you created the .csv file in excel, it's notorious for adding extra 0's and doesn't show them via their UI.

Try recreating your dataset in notepad or even better notepad++.